# How to set id as an unique value for a document in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to set id as an unique value (`say jNsY9nYBnpr12MYNt7D0 or i9sY9nYBnpr12MYNtrAm`) for a document in Elasticsearch before its being persisted. What utility function should we use to auto generate the string in the above form

Comment: You could use a function as fingerprint to generate before insert a unique id, take the field(s) that will be unique in input of this function.

Comment: any reasons not to let it generate by Elasticsearch?

Comment: You should read this before trying to generate unique IDs yourself: https://www.elastic.co/blog/efficient-duplicate-prevention-for-event-based-data-in-elasticsearch and also this http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2014/05/choosing-fast-unique-identifier-uuid.html

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I need the id to update the same record again, need the stickiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save an entity with Spring Data Elasticsearch the methods that do the save will return the saved entity. If the `@Id` field was set to null before saving, the returned entity will have it set to the value that Elasticsearch created.

But as @Val pointed out: Don't do this, there's no need for this.

If you nevertheless want to create the id yourself, you might use the org.elasticsearch.common.UUIDs#base64UUID method, that's what Elasticsearch uses.